# Why do struct arrays not require a membership operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm learning about pointers in C++,and I noticed that if I declare a struct pointer I have to use the arrow membership operator (->) to access the values. Here is an example.

```
client * cp = new client;

cp->age = 30;
```

If I declare a dynamic struct array however, I can use the dot operator instead of the membership operator, like so:

```
client * cp = new client[10];

cp[1].age = 30;
```

Why can I use the dot operator instead of the membership operator if I declare a dynamic struct array?

Comment: The arrow operator is for pointers.

Comment: But aren't I declaring an array pointer in the second example also? @chris

Comment: You have an "array" of `client`, not `client *`.

Comment: Even in the first example, you can write `cp[0].age=30`. Except for `delete/delete[]`, an object is very similar to an array of length 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they're of different types. In your first example `cp` is a `client*`, so you use `operator->()`. In your second example, `cp[1]` is a `client&`, so you use `operator.()`.

If you had:

```
client** cp;
```

*Then* you would use:

```
cp[1]->age = 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

`[n]` uses pointer math to get the instance of element `n` in the array.

In other words:

```
    client* cp = new client[10];
    cp[1].age = 30;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
    client* cp = new client[10];
    (*(cp+1)).age = 30;
```

So now, if you wanted to, you could also do this:

```
    client* cp = new client[10];
    (cp+1)->age = 30;
```

All three of these are the same thing, they're just difference ways of writing them.

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` is of type `*STRUCT`, `STRUCT[]`, or `STRUCT[SOME_SIZE]`, accessing a member will require the use of one indirection (prefixed asterisk) operator.  There are two shorthand notations which implicitly include the asterisk, however.  The notation `foo->bar` will be equivalent to `(*foo).bar`; the notion `foo[bar]` will be equivalent to `*(foo+bar)`.  Thus, `foo[bar].boz` and `(foo+bar)->boz` would both be equivalent to `*((foo+bar)).boz`.  The notion `foo[bar]->boz` would be equivalent to `(**(foo+bar)).boz`, but that would only be appropriate if `foo` were of a type like `**STRUCT`, `*STRUCT[]`, or `*STRUCT[SOME_SIZE]` which needed two indirection operators.